# DDE-сервер на Windows XP

Tags: windows, сервер

А как можно посмотреть, установлен ли и запущен какой-либо DDE сервер в системе?

Comment: Ну где же знатоки!?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Спасибо всем за помощь! :) Ответ: DDE Spy